# Resuming the c# application from the last status

Tags: c#, windows

i want to make a c# Windows App That appears to the user every day with a different Note
or a different Wisdom or whatever .. i put Timers and everything .
but when the user " turned off " the machine or the program it will return to the first Note.
i want it to continue after the last "Note" that the user has been saw .

Answer (score 1):

Then store an identifier to the last note the user sees when you display it. You can for example store this in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

You should save this setting in a settings file. Check this article for code sample.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263230.aspx